# nginx service won't start after reboot AWS Linux server

Tags: linux, nginx, amazon-ec2

A few weeks ago I configured an ec2 server on AWS and database is on RDS and I use nginx as web server. When i reboot server from the AWS console my nginx wont restart automatically. I did this using ***service nginx start*** command.

Is there any way to configure nginx server, So it restarted when i reboot my ec2 instance

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You may configure `nginx` to start automatically on system boot using below command.

```
 #chkconfig nginx on
```

Once you run above command, nginx will be always started whenever system boots.

You may check , if service is configured to start automaticaly on system boot using below command.

```
# chkconfig nginx --list
```

You may disable service auto start using below command

```
# chkconfig nginx off
```